# How do I force user to input a positive integer?

Tags: c, command-line

Force user to input a positive integer and put user in a loop till they do.

So I want everything including characters not allowed just over > 0

I tried the following:

```
while (i < 0) do { 
    printf("please input a number that's positive"); 
    scanf("%d", i); 
}
```

Comment: while (i < 0) do { printf("please input a number that's positive"); scanf("%d", i); }

Comment: A `while` loop works for that. Place it after you accept the user input with as many conditions as you need grouped with && or ||.

Comment: How would I disable any char being inputted?

Comment: @TazB., You can't disable keyboard keys in standard c.

Comment: You could suggest to them what you're expecting, but C can't prohibit human behavior. `printf("Please only enter positive integers!");`.

Comment: there is no way to make it like, if (a > 0 && !char //is that even existant ) do { .. }

Comment: You could write a program that uses the webcam to analyze the user movements, and if the user seems to intent to type a negative number, you shoot a paralyzing dart at him. You will need the paralyzing dart hardware, though. Also you must take care to no paralyze users that simply is hovering his hand over the `-` button, but does not intent to press it.

Comment: VERY FUNNY Ivella. -_- // i did laugh :P

Comment: @Taz - Just FYI, there's no `while (condition) do { }` in C.  There is `do {} while(condition);` and `while(condition) {}`, but not a while do.

Comment: And the condition should be "i <= 0", otherwise it would leave for 0 as well.

Answer (score 11):

For positive integer use the following code

```
int i;
do 
{ 
  printf("please input a number that's positive"); 
  scanf("%d", &i); 
}while (i < 0);
```

The c language provides no error checking for user input. The user is expected to enter the correct data type. For instance, if a user entered a character when an integer value was expected, the program may enter an infinite loop or abort abnormally.

Comment: You must also check the return value of `scanf()`, to ensure it could actually interpret what was typed as a decimal integer. If it returns `0`, then you must clear `stdin` from the characters that can't be read as number.

Comment: 0 would pass this while condition, and 0 is not positive.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these while functions manage the numbers, the int k is the set integer which can only be set below 20, the first while loop makes a statement that calls for another scan if the number is greater than 20
and the second loop prints a k*k box.
Hope this helps.

```
    int main ( )
{
int i, j,k;
printf("Please enter Box size:\n\n");
scanf("%d",&k);
while(k>20){
     printf("Please enter a value below 20\n\n");
     scanf("%d"),&k;
}
while(k<=20)
{
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            printf("#");

        }
    }
     return 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this: declare `char term` and `int wrong = 0`.

```
do {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    if (scanf("%d%c", &n, &term) != 2 || term != '\n' || n <= 0) {
        printf("Only positive numbers.\n");
        wrong = 1;
    }
    else {
        wrong = 0;
        //do something here if correct;
    }
} while (wrong);
```

The code above detects invalid input if the user entered a **mixture of characters and numbers, or negative numbers (and zero)**.

However, it doesn't detect if the user entered trailing zeros in front followed by valid digits eg. `001`or `00000738`. If anyone else could figure this out, please share below. Thanks! :)

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behaviour. Hopefully you meant `fflush(stdout)` so that the user sees the prompt.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another alternative of a function which takes in a `char str[20]` (of say, maybe 20 elements), analyses the string to check for positive integers, and returns a `0` or `1` accordingly. Lastly, convert that string to an integer using `atoi()`.

```
int checkPositiveIntegers(char str[]) {
    char *ptr = str;
    if (*ptr == '-' || *ptr == '0') //checks for negative numbers or zero
        return 1;
    else {
        do {
            if (isdigit(*ptr) == 0) { //checks for non-digit at ptr location; isdigit() returns 0 if non-digit
                return 1;
                break;
            }
            ptr++;
        } while (*ptr != '\0' && *ptr != '\n');
        return 0; //returns 0 if positive integer
    }
}
```

So the function only accepts positive numbers from 1 to 9,999,999,999,999,999,999 (up to 19 digits if `char str[]` holds 20 elements).

However, if you converted the string back to `int n = atoi(str);`, the maximum value it could reach would be 2,147,483,647 since `n` is declared as a signed integer. Play around with different datatypes for exploration.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: There are library functions to convert strings to integers already; there's no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Yes I know that Matt McNabb, I was wondering if some people would like to know how the function was written.