# Breaking a Loop when User enters a positive integer, but not a character

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

Currently, I have a loop in my program that has the format:

```
  #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
    int n;

         while(1)
         {
         printf("Enter a positive number, n");

         scanf("%d",&n);

         if(n>0)
             {
              break;
             }
          }
      }
```

My intention in using the if(n>0) statement was to exit the loop if and only if the user enters a positive integer. However, if the user types in the character "g", for example, the loop will still break, as the ASCII value will be interpreted. How do I form this loop so that it breaks just when the user enters a positive integer value for n?

Comment: In my case it's not breaking up when you enter "g" or any char ... ?

Comment: @Omkant Because `n` is not initialised to anything.  You are seeing undefined behaviour.  See the answer and comments below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22236689/3388865 I have posted a solution to your question in the link above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the return value of [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) which returns the number of successful inputs read:

```
int rc = scanf("%d",&n);

if (rc==1 && n>0) {
  ...
}
```

---

I would suggest you to use [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read the input into a string and convert into integer using [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) as scanf is a poor choice for the reason said by @paddy.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n)` won't remove non-integer bytes from the input stream.  The OP wants to continue looping until an integer is entered.  So you really need to read a single character if the integer input fails and then loop again.